# XSLT not able to find SQL jar files while Transformation using SAXON java Programme

Tags: java, mysql, xml, xslt, saxon

I am doing Transformation of XML to DITA using XSLT and SAXON jar. Normally when I run my Java program in eclipse it working fine but when I create jar file of project and run XSLTL is not able to communicate SQL jar

```
<!-- SQL login -->
<xsl:param name="jdbc.driver" as="xsd:string" select="'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'" />
<xsl:param name="jdbc.database" as="xsd:string" select="'jdbc:mysql://my URL:3306/mydb'" />
<xsl:param name="jdbc.user" as="xsd:string" select="'user'" />
<xsl:param name="jdbc.pass" as="xsd:string" select="'pass'" />
```

I have included saxon9pe.jar, mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar, resolver.jar in my classpath and its working fine from eclipse.

**But my question is when i create jar of my project using maven and invoke the jar file as below**

`java -cp export-data-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.deere.utils.XmlToDitaTransform`

**its not working or saye not able to communicate with sql jar file from xslt**
showing error

```
<xsl:fallback>
    <xsl:message terminate="yes">Cannot access SQL database.</xsl:message>
</xsl:fallback>
```

Comment: There's not enough information here for diagnosis. You might get better error messages (a) if you remove the xsl:fallback, and (b) if you set the configuration property FeatureKeys.TIMING (equivalent to -t on the command line). You don't mention saxon9-sql.jar which also needs to be on your classpath. It could also be a license file issue.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKay I missed the license file. now its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put saxon jar onto your classpath.

Comment: @AshutoshSakalle Do all required jars are corrected packaged in the jar that you are creating?

Comment: Thanks @Ruchika but its not an jars issue I missed out the license key.